# Como puede obtener lo datos este tipo de json, con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola necesito obtener los datos de este json, con JQuery, por ejemplo el dato que necesito es el de "confirmed":

Estoy tratando de consumir estos datos desde una api.

```js
"{\"1\": {\"region\": \"Tarapacá\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 52, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 15.73, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 15.73}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 1, \"lat\": -20.22036, \"long\": -70.13913, \"population\": 330558}}, \"10\": {\"region\": \"Los Lagos\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 380, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 45.85, \"deaths\": 5, \"deaths_per_100k\": 45.85}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 10, \"lat\": -42.300844, \"long\": -73.105387, \"population\": 828708}}, \"11\": {\"region\": \"Aysén\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 7, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 6.79, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 6.79}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 11, \"lat\": -46.1434629, \"long\": -74.3648869, \"population\": 103158}}, \"12\": {\"region\": \"Magallanes\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 415, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 249.2, \"deaths\": 5, \"deaths_per_100k\": 249.2}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 12, \"lat\": -53.3527518, \"long\": -71.5547782, \"population\": 166533}}, \"13\": {\"region\": \"Metropolitana\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 3803, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 53.47, \"deaths\": 36, \"deaths_per_100k\": 53.47}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 13, \"lat\": -33.4372, \"long\": -70.6506, \"population\": 7112808}}, \"14\": {\"region\": \"Los Ríos\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 138, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 14.42, \"deaths\": 3, \"deaths_per_100k\": 14.42}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 14, \"lat\": -40.293129, \"long\": -73.0816727, \"population\": 957224}}, \"15\": {\"region\": \"Arica y Parinacota\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 115, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 50.87, \"deaths\": 1, \"deaths_per_100k\": 50.87}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 15, \"lat\": -18.478518, \"long\": -70.3210596, \"population\": 226068}}, \"16\": {\"region\": \"Ñuble\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 618, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 128.59, \"deaths\": 7, \"deaths_per_100k\": 128.59}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 16, \"lat\": -36.6331577, \"long\": -71.9384821, \"population\": 480609}}, \"2\": {\"region\": \"Antofagasta\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 149, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 24.53, \"deaths\": 1, \"deaths_per_100k\": 24.53}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 2, \"lat\": -23.6463741, \"long\": -70.3980033, \"population\": 607534}}, \"3\": {\"region\": \"Atacama\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 13, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 4.54, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 4.54}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 3, \"lat\": -27.5571783, \"long\": -70.0156882, \"population\": 286168}}, \"4\": {\"region\": \"Coquimbo\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 66, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 8.71, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 8.71}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 4, \"lat\": -30.7546652, \"long\": -70.9005536, \"population\": 757586}}, \"5\": {\"region\": \"Valparaíso\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 273, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 15.03, \"deaths\": 2, \"deaths_per_100k\": 15.03}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 5, \"lat\": -33.0458456, \"long\": -71.6196749, \"population\": 1815902}}, \"6\": {\"region\": \"O’Higgins\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 48, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 5.25, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 5.25}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 6, \"lat\": -34.1708298, \"long\": -70.7444382, \"population\": 914555}}, \"7\": {\"region\": \"Maule\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 141, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 13.49, \"deaths\": 3, \"deaths_per_100k\": 13.49}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 7, \"lat\": -35.5972284, \"long\": -71.48868, \"population\": 1044950}}, \"8\": {\"region\": \"Biobío\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 512, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 32.89, \"deaths\": 2, \"deaths_per_100k\": 32.89}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 8, \"lat\": -37.3391407, \"long\": -72.4106825, \"population\": 1556805}}, \"9\": {\"region\": \"Araucanía\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 795, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 83.05, \"deaths\": 17, \"deaths_per_100k\": 83.05}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 9, \"lat\": -38.6710116, \"long\": -72.2564576, \"population\": 957224}}}"
```

GRACIAS

Comment: Ese es un string, creo que la pregunta necesita más detalles y lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Debes primero parsear el `JSON` que obtienes usando `JSON.parse();`

```js
const json = "{\"1\": {\"region\": \"Tarapacá\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 52, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 15.73, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 15.73}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 1, \"lat\": -20.22036, \"long\": -70.13913, \"population\": 330558}}, \"10\": {\"region\": \"Los Lagos\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 380, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 45.85, \"deaths\": 5, \"deaths_per_100k\": 45.85}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 10, \"lat\": -42.300844, \"long\": -73.105387, \"population\": 828708}}, \"11\": {\"region\": \"Aysén\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 7, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 6.79, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 6.79}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 11, \"lat\": -46.1434629, \"long\": -74.3648869, \"population\": 103158}}, \"12\": {\"region\": \"Magallanes\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 415, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 249.2, \"deaths\": 5, \"deaths_per_100k\": 249.2}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 12, \"lat\": -53.3527518, \"long\": -71.5547782, \"population\": 166533}}, \"13\": {\"region\": \"Metropolitana\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 3803, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 53.47, \"deaths\": 36, \"deaths_per_100k\": 53.47}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 13, \"lat\": -33.4372, \"long\": -70.6506, \"population\": 7112808}}, \"14\": {\"region\": \"Los Ríos\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 138, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 14.42, \"deaths\": 3, \"deaths_per_100k\": 14.42}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 14, \"lat\": -40.293129, \"long\": -73.0816727, \"population\": 957224}}, \"15\": {\"region\": \"Arica y Parinacota\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 115, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 50.87, \"deaths\": 1, \"deaths_per_100k\": 50.87}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 15, \"lat\": -18.478518, \"long\": -70.3210596, \"population\": 226068}}, \"16\": {\"region\": \"Ñuble\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 618, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 128.59, \"deaths\": 7, \"deaths_per_100k\": 128.59}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 16, \"lat\": -36.6331577, \"long\": -71.9384821, \"population\": 480609}}, \"2\": {\"region\": \"Antofagasta\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 149, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 24.53, \"deaths\": 1, \"deaths_per_100k\": 24.53}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 2, \"lat\": -23.6463741, \"long\": -70.3980033, \"population\": 607534}}, \"3\": {\"region\": \"Atacama\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 13, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 4.54, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 4.54}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 3, \"lat\": -27.5571783, \"long\": -70.0156882, \"population\": 286168}}, \"4\": {\"region\": \"Coquimbo\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 66, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 8.71, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 8.71}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 4, \"lat\": -30.7546652, \"long\": -70.9005536, \"population\": 757586}}, \"5\": {\"region\": \"Valparaíso\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 273, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 15.03, \"deaths\": 2, \"deaths_per_100k\": 15.03}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 5, \"lat\": -33.0458456, \"long\": -71.6196749, \"population\": 1815902}}, \"6\": {\"region\": \"O’Higgins\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 48, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 5.25, \"deaths\": 0, \"deaths_per_100k\": 5.25}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 6, \"lat\": -34.1708298, \"long\": -70.7444382, \"population\": 914555}}, \"7\": {\"region\": \"Maule\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 141, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 13.49, \"deaths\": 3, \"deaths_per_100k\": 13.49}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 7, \"lat\": -35.5972284, \"long\": -71.48868, \"population\": 1044950}}, \"8\": {\"region\": \"Biobío\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 512, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 32.89, \"deaths\": 2, \"deaths_per_100k\": 32.89}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 8, \"lat\": -37.3391407, \"long\": -72.4106825, \"population\": 1556805}}, \"9\": {\"region\": \"Araucanía\", \"regionData\": {\"04/13/2020\": {\"confirmed\": 795, \"confirmed_per_100k\": 83.05, \"deaths\": 17, \"deaths_per_100k\": 83.05}}, \"regionInfo\": {\"_id\": 9, \"lat\": -38.6710116, \"long\": -72.2564576, \"population\": 957224}}}";
















const parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);

//Una vez teniendo el JSON parseado puedes acceder a las propiedades de este
//directamente usando un . seguido de la propiedad asi:

console.log(parsedJson[1].regionData["04/13/2020"].confirmed);
```

Si deseas obtener todas las propiedades `confirmed` en un `array` deberas usar un `ciclo` dentro de un ciclo, por ejemplo  un ciclo `for in`, no te explicare como hacerlo deberás investigar y pensar en ello amigo, ya te di una parte, debes pensar en la otra parte, consideralo una forma de ayudarte a mejorar, mejoramos atravez de equivocarnos y experimentar, intenta obtener todas las propiedades `confirmed` de ese objeto en un array, se que puedes, yo ahí te obtuve la primera como ejemplo.